# MS SQL last record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just try to write MS SQL statement to get LAST DATA from database, unfortunately when i add there DESC LIMIT 1 it says wrong syntax despite the fact it looks OK to me.

Can somebody with more skill look at it?

```
Select
  sum(spareparts), 
  month(calculationdate) 
from cz_axnmrs_calculations 
where CASE_ID in (select case_id 
                  from cz_axnmrs_cases 
                  where insurer_memberid = 'MM-O-5B57274F') 
and YEAR(calculationdate)='2014'  
group by month(calculationdate) DESC LIMIT 1
```

LIKE THIS it work:

```
Select 
  sum(spareparts), 
  month(calculationdate) 
from cz_axnmrs_calculations 
where CASE_ID in (select case_id 
                  from cz_axnmrs_cases 
                  where insurer_memberid = 'MM-O-5B57274F') 
and YEAR(calculationdate)='2014'  
group by month(calculationdate)
```

Comment: @Matt: If you edit a post make sure you fix everything. Make it worth the time of the edit-reviewers.

Comment: "looks op to me" like "totally ignoring any syntax that you never bothered to look up"?

Comment: @juergend Yeh sorry, missed the general text, i wanted to clean up the code and answer the question first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL server uses `TOP` instead of `LIMIT` to restrict number of records.

Your query becomes:

```
Select top 1 
  sum(spareparts), 
  month(calculationdate) 
from cz_axnmrs_calculations 
where CASE_ID in (select case_id 
                  from cz_axnmrs_cases 
                  where insurer_memberid = 'MM-O-5B57274F') 
and YEAR(calculationdate)='2014'  
group by month(calculationdate) DESC
```

Comment: Maybe i have one more question if you have second.
Right now i select LAST SUM and MONTH from All cases.

But what if I want sum just from LAST calculation from all cases?

So result should be same as before add that TOP but with smaller numbers (because you don't count all calculations)

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean by the `last calculation from all cases`.  Put together a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with example data and post a question with the output you want.

Comment: Fiddle is temporarry unavaliable. What this code does (if we remove TOP1) it take all spareparts and count them (sum), but i want to just get last sparepart instead of count all.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012+, Microsoft supports the ANSI standard OFFSET clause.  You can write this as:

```
Select sum(spareparts), month(calculationdate)
from cz_axnmrs_calculations
where CASE_ID in (select case_id from cz_axnmrs_cases where insurer_memberid = 'MM-O-5B57274F') and
      YEAR(calculationdate)='2014'
group by month(calculationdate) DESC
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select TOP 1 sum(spareparts), month(calculationdate) from cz_axnmrs_calculations 
WHERE CASE_ID in (select case_id 
FROM cz_axnmrs_cases WHERE insurer_memberid = 'MM-O-5B57274F') AND YEAR(calculationdate)='2014'  
GROUP BY month(calculationdate)
```